# Change order of completion list in Visual Studio using an extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I am trying to write an extension that changes the order of the completion items in Visual Studio, specifically for C#. However, no matter how I try, I always seem to end up in a dead-end.

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text;

namespace CompletionTest
{
    internal class TestCompletionSource : ICompletionSource
    {
        private static CompletionSet2 _completionSet;

        private readonly TestCompletionSourceProvider _sourceProvider;
        private readonly ITextBuffer _textBuffer;

        private bool _isDisposed;

        public TestCompletionSource(TestCompletionSourceProvider sourceProvider, ITextBuffer textBuffer)
        {
            _sourceProvider = sourceProvider;
            _textBuffer     = textBuffer;
        }

        void ICompletionSource.AugmentCompletionSession(ICompletionSession session, IList<CompletionSet> completionSets)
        {
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!_isDisposed)
            {
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
                _isDisposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The AugmentCompletionSession method is called two times, the first time the completionSets parameter is empty. The second time, the completionSets parameter is filled with all the completions that Visual Studio generates. I want to reorder this list, or add another completion list where the order is different and that's where the problems start.

I can use the set provided by Visual Studio and reorder it and add it to the completionSets parameter. I then see two lists, selectable using tabs within the intellisense dropdown list. However, if I select my own list, and press enter to insert the item into the text view, it inserts the selected item of the normal unordered list. I can insert it using the mouse, but obviously that is kind of annoying.

Does anyone know how to fix this or is there any other way to do this?